# Pandas Sticky Column Headers using Styler not working (sticky index rows works great)

Tags: pandas, sticky, pandas-styles

I am using pandas 1.5.3 in Flask. This code creates a sticky index column but not sticky column headers:

```
bigdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 100))
dfhtml = bigdf.style.set_sticky(axis="index").set_sticky(axis="columns").to_html()
dfhtml = Markup(dfhtml)
```

[image: Index column frozen]
You can see that the index column freezes when I scroll horizontally but the column headers don't freeze.

Weird thing is I have another DF in another identical environment with multi-index column headers it seems to work!

I have searched and found lots of comments on this problem associated with Jupyter notebooks. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

This works, provided you have a sliding bar.

```
bigdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 20))
bigdf.style.set_sticky(axis="index").set_sticky(axis="columns")
```

In my case, the vertical sliding bar can be toggled on and off by clicking on the left part of the cell (to the left of the index)

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  And, I'm and idiot!  I have a sticky navbar!  It was working the whole time but frozen BEHIND the navbar. :(  I just needed to make the th tag taller. :(

Comment: Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm and idiot! I have a sticky navbar! It was working the whole time but frozen BEHIND the navbar. :( I just needed to make the th tag taller. :(